# Uppercase first letter of only the first word

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

How do you force the first letter of the first word in a field to uppercase?

Answer (score 10):

Asked before: [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

The correct answer:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var myString = "hello world";
alert(capitalizeFirstLetter(myString));
```

And it would alert `Hello world`

Comment: First letter of the first WORD. Won't work if the first char in the string is a space.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript, it's enough with the CSS `:first-letter` pseudo-element.

If you want do it via JavaScript, it has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript):

```
str.replace(/^\w/, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); })
```